# segfault on removal from first node in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

The remove function for my singly linked chain does not work when I remove the very first node. Say I have {33,40,50} when I try and remove 33 i get a segfault, but the other two work fine. I think I just need some fresh eyes to see what i messed up in my remove function.

remove function

```
bool Set::remove(int X)
{
        bool Flag = false;
        Node * Prev = Head;
        Node * Curr = Head->Succ;
        //unsigned Z = 0;

        while(Curr->Item != X)
        {
                Prev = Curr;
                Curr = Curr->Succ;
        }
        Prev->Succ =Curr->Succ;
        delete Curr;
        Num--;
        Flag = true;
        return Flag;
}
```

Comment: Maybe instead of "prev" and "curr" you need "curr" and "next"?

Comment: `Curr` starts out pointing to `40`; it will never point to `33`.

Comment: Do you really need this Flag variable? I think you are missing something. Infinite loop?

Comment: What do you think will happen if you try to `remove` a value that isn't in the list?

Comment: FYI - unless you're doing this for school, or for an embedded device or similar where you're worried about severely restrictive size/memory/performance constraints, you should probably just use STL's `std::list` rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you start with `Curr = Head->Succ` which is already past 33(`Curr->item` is 40). You are also never checking to see if its at the end of the list. So you're accessing memory that is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether you went through the end of the list.

And you should start on the first element rather than the second (which, in this case, causes you to go through the list and try to continue further).

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the search at the wrong place:

Change from:

```
    Node * Prev = Head;
    Node * Curr = Head->Succ;
```

to:

```
    Node * Prev = null;
    Node * Curr = Head;
```

But the real problem for segfault is that you haven't considered the scenario for a terminating condition if the specified element is not found in your linked list.

You might implement a terminating condition as follows:

```
bool Set::remove(int X)
{
        Node * Prev = Head;
        Node * Curr = Head->Succ;
        while(Curr->Item != X)
        {
                Prev = Curr;
                Curr = Curr->Succ;
                if ( null == Curr ) {
                    // If you've reached the end of your
                    // linked list and haven't found the item
                    // yet, give up looking and return
                    return false;
                }
        }
        Prev->Succ =Curr->Succ;
        delete Curr;
        Num--;
        return true;
}
```

Note: I also cleaned up your code a bit to remove `bool Flag` as it's unnecessary.

Comment: I added an if to check if X is present before going into the loops, but I am still getting a segfault at `Prev->Succ = Curr->Succ;` which I understand, but I am not sure how to fix.

Comment: @sharkman check updated answer, it shows you one way you might implement a terminating condition in this case.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it did not make any difference. however if i change both prev and curr to head initially. it will actually update 33, but to some random number (which i assume to be a memory address in int)

Answer (score 1):

Your Curr variable starts on the **SECOND** location. Head points to the first location, while Curr points to the location that head points two(which is second!). This gives an infinite loop and crashes the program. Start `curr` at `head` instead of this

Answer (score 0):

Curr is initialized:

```
Node * Curr = Head->Succ;
```

meaning that when you make

```
while(Curr->Item != X)
```

you are skipping the "head" value. Since Curr->Item will never be 33(the head value) you will keep going to Succ until eventually you reach the NULL pointer at the end of the list. 
You are not checking if you have reached the end of the list in your while so you get a segmentation fault when doing

```
Curr->Item != X
OR
Curr = Curr->Succ;
```

Try initializing:

```
Node * Curr = Head;
```